# New installation of Umbraco which now ignores .net web api routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, umbraco, umbraco8

I have a `.net web api` project, which has an empty `Umbraco` installation in it. 
We plan to query `Umbraco` content via nodeid's and return this data back via the `web api` to the SPA application.

The issue I have is when I run the `web api` project instead of being greeted with my `web api` home page, I'm shown the following:

[image]

It seems that `Umbraco` is now ignoring my `web api` project completely, even when I type `home/index`  I'm still shown the above.

I've searched the web and found the following [Configuring custom Web api routing for Umbraco sites](https://www.andreasjohansson.eu/technical-blog/configuring-custom-web-api-routing-for-umbraco-sites/) yet my issue still persists.

Can someone assists in how I go making `Umbraco` include my `web api` routes?

I'm new to Umbraco and Web Api combination so any help would be highly greatful.

Comment: Why do you clutter your question with code fragments that aren't actually code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the web api routes don't have anything to do with Umbraco content items, you can try adding the path "home/index" to the AppSetting "umbracoReservedPaths" in the web.config to make sure Umbraco doesn't try to look for a matching content item for it.